# Pass argument via variable

Tags: php, mysqli

this is my code...
docrow('&ddname') is not passing.if I am using docrow('Jhon') then my code is all right.it give 3 number of row in returns.but what's wrong with docrow('&ddname')? it give me 0 row in returns.though there have 3 rows!

```
<?php 
$ddname="Jhon"; 
include 'config.php';
//my database connection
function docrow($name){
    global $conn;
    $sqlquery=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT id,name,docname,discount,docget from income where docname='$name'");
    $countrow=mysqli_num_rows($sqlquery);
    return $countrow;
}
echo docrow('$ddname');
?>
```

Comment: inside the single quotes everything consider as string so .no need that single quotes echo docrow($ddname);

Comment: $ddname is a variable don't include quotes `echo docrow($ddname);`

Comment: i checked your code i is working fine . don not include single quotes on variables you can directly put variables . Example  insisted of this   `echo docrow('$ddname');`  do this `echo docrow($ddname);`. you will result

Comment: thankyou!! now it's fine!!

Comment: @MustaqueAhmed please think of [accepting an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass the connection as a parameter to your function, and don't use quotes around your arguments when you pass them to a function.

```
<?php
$ddname = "Jhon";
include 'config.php';
//my database connection
function docrow($name, $conn)
{
    $sqlquery = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT id,name,docname,discount,docget from income where docname='$name'");
    return mysqli_num_rows($sqlquery);
}

echo docrow($ddname, $conn);
?>
```

[Please read more about the difference between single and double quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single)
and [global variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5166087/php-global-in-functions)

Comment: he accessed by gloabl did you notice that global $conn;

Comment: Yes I did, I think it's better to stay away from global variables.

Comment: is there any issue using global variable ?

Comment: I think a function should not depend/rely on the global scope code

Answer (score 2):

Try it:

```
<?php
$ddname="Jhon"; 
include 'config.php';
//my database connection
function docrow($name){
    global $conn;
    $sqlquery=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT id,name,docname,discount,docget from income where docname='$name'");
    $countrow=mysqli_num_rows($sqlquery);
    return $countrow;
}
echo docrow($ddname);
?>
```